# Add and/sum/offset condition to row delete code

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below, which deletes all rows for which the value in Column C is not a named range ("ReferenceLocations").

```
' Defines variables
Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range, LastRow As Long, x As Long, TestRange As Range, MyRange As Range

'DELETE IRRELEVANT LOCATIONS
' Defines LastRow as the last row of data based on column C
LastRow = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


' Sets check range as C1 to the last row of C
Set cRange = Range("C2:C" & LastRow)


' For each cell in the check range, working from the bottom upwards
For x = cRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With cRange.Cells(x)
        ' If the cell does not contain one of the values listed in "ReferenceLocations" named range, delete rows
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Range("ReferenceLocations"), 0)) Then
   .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
' Check next cell, working upwards
Next x
```

My goal now is to add an And condition to the "IsError...Then" line, which will sum the values of cells to the right from column (X) to Column P, with the (X) given by the value in a cell on another sheet (probably an offset). The function should only delete the entire row if the condition in code above is met AND the sum of the cells in column (X) to P = 0.

Comment: When you say "right from column (X)" do you mean right from C:C, I suppose. Am I wrong? Then, what do you mean by "with the (X) given by the value in a cell on another sheet (probably an offset)"? This is completely incomprehensible... What other sheet? Should we guess? Should the "(x) given by..." meaning the same row of a specific sheet (the same column?)? You should clarify this aspects if you really need help...

Comment: Is this happening in one workbook? Is it the workbook containing this code and/or containing the named range? How does `Sheets(Sheet1)` work? is `Sheet1` the code name or the (tab) name of a worksheet, or just a string variable? Is the named range in the `Sheet1` worksheet? if not, what is its worksheet's name or code name? Where is the offset located i.e. in which cell of which worksheet? Please do clarify, best by editing your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of the sum, we just need to give a range to the `SUM` formula. We know that we're starting from a cell, some columns to the right of `cRange.Cells(x)` which can be written as `cRange.Cells(x).Offset(, y)` which would be something like "K5" if `x` was 4 and `y` was 8.  The second cell we want to get to is `cRange.Cells(x).EntireRow.Cells(16)` which would be "P5" if `x` was 4. So we can just use the `Range` function to create a range that stretches from one cell to the other. `Range(cRange.Cells(x).Offset(, y), cRange.Cells(x).EntireRow.Cells(16))`. This would be "K5:P5" if `x` was 4 and `y` was 8.

To make use of the `With` statement, and to not repeat the object inside the with block, we can rephrase it as `.Parent.Range(.Offset(, y), .EntireRow.Cells(16))`

```vb
    If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Range("ReferenceLocations"), 0)) _
    And WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Parent.Range(.Offset(, y), .EntireRow.Cells(16))) = 0 _
    Then
       .EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I realize now that (X) has created some confusion. Instead let's call it (Y), where (Y) refers to an offset to the right of column C. I want to be able to define (Y) in a cell that the user inputs on a Control Panel sheet. So if I enter Y=8 in my control panel, I want the code to sum K:P in the row being checked by this code.

Comment: @vjr2109 I have corrected my answer to include that offset variable `y`.

Comment: Works! Many thanks, and sorry for the confusion.